# Splitting a string into parameters like a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parameters, split, query-string

I normally use this code for getting parameters from a URL:

```
var QueryString = function () {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
}();
```

However, I would like to pass a string rather than use `window.location`. However `search.substring` isn't valid for this.

The string will be just like a url: a=this&b=that

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var QueryString = function (query) {
  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  //var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
        // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
    }
  } 
    return query_string;
};
//Sample Call
QueryString('a=this&b=that');
```

Pass `query` as a param to function definition and comment that `var query= ...` declaration inside function, and remove the self executing `()` clause;

Now call from anywhere `QueryString('a=this&b=that')`